# How to achieve centered line chart?

Tags: charts, chart.js, linechart, c3.js

[image]

I'm really new to chart.js and c3.js and I want to make this form of chart.

I've read these library's document, but I didn't found any clue about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "centered"? That you simply want a line drawn in the centre of the plot area?

Comment: Also, c3.js and Chart.js are distinct libraries. Are you using both? Or are you trying to learn one? Your example image looks like it was generated by c3.js.

Comment: @timclutton 1. I want to draw an line chart which located in center 2. I'll try one which can make it simply.

Comment: That's not very easy in chart.js because it's not possible (I really don't know why) to use a linear xAxis (at least when you're labels (xAxis values) are irregular and not a time). You would have to use a workaround. Can you explain you data, what is xAxis and yAxis?

Comment: And can you explain your reasoning behind this? Why do you need extra space on the left and right side of you data? chart.js usually centers your data with cropping unneccessary labels and that's usually really good.